# How to get the first element of a string split with space

Tags: bash

I am trying to get the name of the user after `su` in a bash script. I used the following code:

```
user=`who am i`
#user <- "user4035     pts/0        2017-04-02 05:13 (my-hostname)"
userarray=($user)
#userarray <- ["user4035", "pts/0", "2017-04-02 05:13", "(my-hostname)"]
user=${userarray[0]}
#outputs "user4035"
echo $user
```

It works correctly, but is it possible to achieve the same result with less number of commands?

Comment: Try this: `echo $USER` or `id -un`

Comment: @Cyrus `id -un` prints "root" after I `su`, but I need to get the name of the user that did the `su`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `bash` *parameter-expansion* without needing to use arrays,

```
myUser=$(who am i)
printf "%s\n" "${myUser%% *}"
user4035
```

(or) just use a simple `awk`, command,

```
who am i | awk '{print $1}'
user4035
```

i.e. in  a variable do,

```
myUser=$(who am i | awk '{print $1}')
printf "%s\n" "$myUser"
```

(or) if your script is run with `sudo` privileges, you can use this `bash` environment-variable,

```
printf "%s\n" "${SUDO_USER}"
```

Comment: that's actually _less_ efficient since the OP's code uses shell builtin variable operations

Comment: @Alnitak: Appreciate your feedback, thought OP needed _lesser_ number of commands and not worried about the _kind_ of commands needed.

Comment: true, but frankly I think the OP is asking the wrong question ;-)

Comment: @Inian Sorry for not mentioning efficiency in the question.

Comment: @user4035: If that is your point, I don't think using arrays is that efficient, use the parameter expansion syntax in the beginning of my answer.

Comment: @user4035: The array implementation is not _less_ efficient itself, its just that your requirement is pretty _trivial_ to actually start debating efficiency :)  it just comes down to using an _array_ vs just a _variable_

Comment: ROFL. Typical for the `bash` community here. _Use `{...}` instead of `(....)` because the later forks a subshell..._ or  _Use parameter expansion because a fork/exec is inefficient..._ and such... Sure, if someone will use zilion times in a loop `$(echo $var | grep | sed)` for a thing solvable by parameter expansion - will say OK, but - OMG - who cares in such script?! few miliseconds +- doesn't matter...

Comment: @jm666: Nice point :) that is why my comment above, this is too trivial a task to start discussing efficiency!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Nice! but `bash`-ism introduced with `<()` :) , Again are we even worried bout that now?

Comment: I thought the question was tagged Bash. Oh, wait, it is.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Not doubting the efficiency of the suggestion! just a note on it!

Answer (score 11):

Another simple solution is `cut` with custom delimiter:

```
user=$(who am I | cut -d ' ' -f1)
echo $user
```

Comment: Just what I needed to split a string with a semicolon.

Answer (score 7):

You can remove one line of commands by creating the array on one line, but it's not worth doing any more than that because at least you're only using shell builtins, and not forking any additional commands:

```
who=(`who am i`)
user=${who[0]}
```